# Recommended books for measure theory and functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, book-recommendation

at university we learnt a little bit about measure theory and functional analysis. 
In fact , I intend to learn more and more to reach advanced level in these two subjects.
Therefore, I would be very grateful if anyone could suggest recommended books' names.

Comment: why you dont use the search? There are a lot of questions over book recommendations for measure theory, and others about functional analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 'Functional Analysis' by Haim Brezis and for Measure theory try 'Real and Complex Analysis ' by Walter Rudin.

Comment: You meant this book http://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387709130

Comment: Yes. Also it contains lot of interesting exercises.

Comment: Apart from Rudin's RCA I recommend Real and Abstract Analysis by Hewitt and Stromberg. Rudin's also good.